Sauna Shower Sealant
We have a 1999ish model of an Ariel sauna shower we inherited when we bought our home. There are layers of silicone caulk with embedded mold.  I started to remove them to strip it clean but realized I had cut into what looks like a rubber trim (it was also discolored and moldy).  Should I cut all of the rubber out?  If yes, is silicone caulk enough to water seal it?  It looks like the gap is about 1/4 inch?

Which part of this is the "rubber trim"? Have you searched the internet for the brand/model of your shower to look at installation instructions to confirm whether there's a rubber gasket of some sort or if it says to install then simply caulk?

Found installation video and the tan colored rubber is indeed a gasket seal at the bottom of the original prefab shower wall.  I can’t take the unit apart to replace it.  I assume the best approach is to use a pro strength mold remover on the strip, clean up as much of the straggly bits that are loose and silicone caulk the heck out of it to prevent water damage.  Any other ideas? Does that sound like a realistic plan?

Yes, cut/scrape out all that moldy stuff until you can see what you are really dealing with. Clean and dry, then use high quality caulk to seal; make sure to use caulk for which the gap is within listed width tolerance.
